# In React Laravel Mix App, Page titles not reflecting from React component when tested with SEO tools

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, seo, laravel-mix

I have a React application built using Laravel Mix, where I set page titles dynamically using **React Helmet** on component itself but when I test my application's SEO using external websites &  tools, the page titles displayed are not the ones set in the React components but instead taken from **app.blade.php**. I've seen in other similar applications it's working fine.

Here's an example of how I'm setting the page title in my React component:

```
return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>My Page Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My Page Title" />
      </Helmet>
      <div>
        <PageWrapperStyled>
        </PageWrapperStyled>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Here's my app.blade.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>My Page Title</title>
    <link href="{{mix('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Inria+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div id="example"></div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    @if (env('APP_ENV') == 'local')
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
    @endif
</body>

</html>
```

How can I ensure that the page titles set in the React components are accurately reflected when testing SEO using external tools? Is there a specific configuration or setup ?

Please Help, Thanks in advance...

I tried removing the title from the app.blade.php file to prevent any conflict but this results in the SEO checking tools showing null or empty titles. I also tried using @yield('title') in app.blade.php but these didn't work

Comment: You need to get SSR and [Helmet server usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet#server-usage) working in Laravel somehow.

Comment: Not Sure about SSR, but the application that I've created is the copy of an app on which's page titles & other SEO tags are working fine & it's not using SSR.